# Good review article for Euler's Constant $\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

I am writing a paper on Euler's constant (or Euler-Mascheroni constant) $\gamma$ with 4 other people and we are looking for a good review article on the subject. So far we haven't found anything. A lot of specific papers, but nothing general. What review/general articles would you reccommend on $\gamma$ and its properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting the references given in the comments:

- The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)
- The book [Gamma: Exploring Euler's Constant](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691178103/gamma)
  by Julian Havil
- The review paper [Euler's constant: Euler's work and modern developments](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1856) by Jeffery Lagarias
- Section 1.5 of the book [Mathematical Constants](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/recreational-mathematics/mathematical-constants) by
  Steven R. Finch